# How to define environment variables in svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I'm new to svelte and I'd like to use some environment variables like `base_url` in different components. I know that I can define store, and put those values there,like:

```js
const Store = writable([
  { 
    base_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
  }
]);
```

and each time I import store to compoenent using

```js
let base_url = "";
import Store from "../stores/Store.js";
Store.subscribe((data) => {
  base_url = data.base_url  
});
```

But that involves lots of boilerplate code, and I find store more suitable for dynamic data rather than static values. So I'm wondering what is the more idomatic/convenient way to do so?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly call `subscribe` you can use the `$` [auto-subscription](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions) shorthand

Answer (score 2):

The way I mostly go about this is to create a file named `environment.js` or sth like that and put all my environment variables in there. Then I just need to import them where I need them.

```js
// environment.js:
export const base_url = '..';

// somewhere-else.js/somecomponent.svelte:
import { base_url } from './path/to/environment.js';
```

This will also make it easier to replace these variables depending on whether you are in development or production mode. You can then easily add replacement solutions (replacing the variable value with what's fitting) which depend on what setup you use (Rollup: rollup-plugin-replace, Vite: env files, etc).

Answer (score 0):

My structure is like this:

`src/config/endpoint.js`

```js
//src/config/endpoint.js

let base_url = '';

switch(ENV){
  case ENV_PROD:
    base_url = 'http://www.example.com/api';
  break;
  case ENV_TEST:
    base_url = 'http://www.example.com/test_api';
  break;
  default:
    base_url = 'http://localhost:3301/api';
  break;
}

export base_url;
```

Now import `endpoint.js` in your components or file and use like this:

```js
//App.svelte

import { base_url } from './../config/endpoint.js';
```

Comment: Thanks for the expample! When running it I get the error 'base_url' has already been declared" - it's just the let above exported, no const export below?